# how to calculate the median for groups separately in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply

Little example of data

```
    df=structure(list(Dt = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), .Label = c("2018-02-20 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-21 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-23 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-24 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-26 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-27 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-01 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-02 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-03 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-04 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-05 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-06 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-07 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-08 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-09 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-10 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-11 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-12 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-13 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-14 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-15 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-16 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-17 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-18 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-19 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-23 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-26 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-29 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-30 00:00:00.000"), class = "factor"), ItemRelation = c(158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L
), stuff = c(200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1000L, 2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 400L, 700L, 
200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1000L, 
2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 400L, 700L), num = c(1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Dt", "ItemRelation", 
"stuff", "num", "year", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-78L))
```

now for each group
ItemRelation    +num    +year i have to calculate the median.
If i use this solution

```
# df with action 0 and stuff > 0
v <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 0),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))]

# df with action 1 and stuff > 0
w <- df$stuff[intersect(which(df$action == 1),
                        which(df$stuff > 0))]


# calulating the median of v for the last 5 observations
l <- length(v)
m0 <- median(v[(l-4):l]) # taking the median of the last 5 observations
# computing the final difference
m <- median(w) - m0
```

i calculate median for all group at once, but i have to calculate for
each group separately.
How can i perform it?

here expected output

```
ItemRelation    num year    value
158043       1459   2018    45
158043      234    2018     67
```

post edited. Note that value are not real, the medians will another, i just wanted to show what i wan as output

## Edit

The action column has only two values 0 and 1. i must calculate median by stuff for 1 category of action, then median by stuff of zero category of action, using last five integer values before one category. I just take the last 5 observations, It is necessary to take the last 5 observations in the zero category of action, but only the integer value, and not calculate the median by all values of zero category. In our case this is

```
200
3600
700
1000
2600
```

then substract median of zero category from median of one category.

The number of observations by stuff in the zero category of action can vary from 0-10. If we have 10 integer values of zero category, we take last five. If there is only 1,2,3,4,5 values integer, we subtract median of real number of integer values. If we have only 0 without integer , we just substact 0.

But code must calculate the median by zero category, but 5 last obs before one category.

Note, instead of 0, there may be other values for the zero category of action.

Comment: Your sample data only has 1459 for `num` while your expected output has `num == 234`. Please fix.

Comment: @useR, you are right, i fixed it. Please check.

Comment: See the documentation for `tapply`

Comment: @Noah i tried use lapply and tapply but, didn't get the result. How to do correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be achieved using `dplyr` and following below mentioned steps. Please find comments in code below for approach.

**Note:** It seems that sample data from OP is not very meaningful as such.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(stuff > 0) %>%  #First filter out for stuff > 0 which of our interest
  group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    mutate(m = median(stuff[action==1]),
           m0 = median(tail(stuff[action==0], 5))) %>%  # Calculate m and m0 for all rows
  filter(action == 1) %>%  # Now keep only rows with action == 1
  mutate(m = m-m0) %>%
  select(-Dt,-m0,-action)

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups: ItemRelation, num, year [2]
# ItemRelation stuff   num  year     m
# <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1       158043   400  1459  2018  -450
# 2       158043   700  1459  2018  -450
# 3          234   400  1459  2018  -450
# 4          234   700  1459  2018  -450
```

Comment: MKR, can I ask you to help in this related topic. it is the continuation of your answer, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948339/multiply-median-for-groups-separately-in-r-by-condition

Comment: @D.Joe I have added an answer to your new question. Have a look. You can accept answer if meet your expectation so that it will be helpful to future users.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `group_by` and `summarize` from the `dplyr` package:

```r
library(dplyr)

# median of groups
medians <- df %>%
    group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    summarize(med = median(stuff, na.rm = T))

# median of nonzero values in each group
medians <- df %>%
    filter(stuff>0) %>%
    group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    summarize(med = median(stuff, na.rm = T))


subtract <- function(x){return(x[1]-x[2])}
median_diffs <- medians %>%
                group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
                mutate(med_diff = subtract(med))
```

Comment: Özgen Eren, please pay attention and you will see, that the which i gave work with categories of action. we calculate median for group  and action=1, the median for group and action =0, thant subtact it. Please consider my code.

Comment: Özgen, i edited post to clear my question, can you check it?

Comment: also you might need to make sure order is correct in x. you could pass 2 variables action and med if that is important