# multiply median for groups separately in R by condition

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply

I have this dataset

```
df=structure(list(Dt = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L), .Label = c("2018-02-20 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-21 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-23 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-24 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-26 00:00:00.000", "2018-02-27 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-02-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-01 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-02 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-03 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-04 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-05 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-06 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-07 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-08 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-09 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-10 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-11 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-12 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-13 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-14 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-15 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-16 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-17 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-18 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-19 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-20 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-21 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-22 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-23 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-24 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-25 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-26 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-27 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-28 00:00:00.000", "2018-03-29 00:00:00.000", 
"2018-03-30 00:00:00.000"), class = "factor"), ItemRelation = c(158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 
158043L, 158043L, 158043L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 
234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L, 234L
), stuff = c(200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1000L, 2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 400L, 700L, 
200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 700L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1000L, 
2600L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 400L, 700L), num = c(1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 
1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L, 1459L), year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L), action = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Dt", "ItemRelation", 
"stuff", "num", "year", "action"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-78L))
```

The next  operation was performed on this data.
1. the operation of calculating the median for the first category of the action and the zero category of action by stuff ( last five non-zero observations).
2.then the median of the zero category was subtracted from the median in the first category.
Solution of MKR is very accurate.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(stuff > 0) %>%  #First filter out for stuff > 0 which of our interest
  group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
    mutate(m = median(stuff[action==1]),
           m0 = median(tail(stuff[action==0], 5))) %>%  # Calculate m and m0 for all rows
  filter(action == 1) %>%  # Now keep only rows with action == 1
  mutate(m = m-m0) %>%
  select(-Dt,-m0,-action
```

How to do that the calculated result for each group was multiplied by the number of ones by action, but only for those that are more than zero by stuff.
For example, for stratum

```
ItemRelation    num     year
158043          1459    2018
```

we have 4 ones in action, and only two ones by stuff more then zero
so the calculated result (m) we multiply on two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is already filter for `stuff>0` in `dplyr - chain`. The`n()` represent the count per group where `stuff>0` and `action ==1`. Hence, one can multiply the final value of `m` with `n()`. At the end, `distinct` will ensure that duplicate rows has been removed.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(stuff > 0) %>%  #First filter out for stuff > 0 which of our interest
  group_by(ItemRelation, num, year) %>%
  mutate(m = median(stuff[action==1]),
         m0 = median(tail(stuff[action==0], 5))) %>%  # Calculate m and m0 for all rows
  filter(action == 1) %>%  # Now keep only rows with action == 1
  mutate(m = (m-m0)*n()) %>%
  select(-Dt,-m0,-action, - stuff) %>% distinct()

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups: ItemRelation, num, year [2]
#   ItemRelation   num  year     m
#          <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1       158043  1459  2018  -900
# 2          234  1459  2018  -900
```